# asyncio 'function' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python-3.6, python-asyncio, django-channels

I'm trying to send message to the client every 30 seconds till client disconnects in django channels. Below is the piece of code written to achieve it using asyncio. But getting the error `"AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send'"`. I haven't used asyncio before, so tried many possibilities and all of them results in some kind of error (because of my inexperience).
Could someone please help me how can this be solved.

Below is the code :

```
class HomeConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = "home"
        self.room_group_name = self.room_name
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()
        self.connected = True
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        task = loop.create_task(self.send_response)
        loop.run_until_complete(task)

    async def send_response(self):
        while self.connected:
            sent_by = Message.objects.filter(notification_read=False).exclude(
                last_sent_by=self.scope["user"]).values("last_sent_by__username")

            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'notification_by': list(sent_by)
            }))
            asyncio.sleep(30)

    
    def disconnect(self, close_code):

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.connected = False
```

something might be wrong at below portion of the code i believe:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
task = loop.create_task(self.send_response)
loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

using `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` instead of creating `new_event_loop()` results in :

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.
```

Comment: You need `loop.create_task(self.send_response())` (note the extra parentheses), but there's still a good chance that the code won't work as you'd like it to because `run_until_complete` (as the name implies) blocks until the given task completes.

Comment: yeah adding the parenthesis helped to call the send_response function. But resulting in new error " RuntimeError: You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly."

Comment: If you're already running inside the event loop, maybe you should heed the advice provided by the error message. For example, you could inherit from `AsyncWebsocketConsumer`, make `connect` an `async def`, modify the code to be like [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/consumers.html#asyncwebsocketconsumer), and just `await self.channel_layer.group_add(...)`. Spawn `self.send_response` with `asyncio.create_task(self.send_response())` without `run_until_complete`.

Comment: it's perfect. Thanks much for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this solution as answer because i searched a lot on how to send data to client without client requesting in django-channels. But couldn't find any complete explanation or answers. So hope this would help someone who is in the situation i was in.

Thanks to **user4815162342** for the help he provided for solving the issue i had.

```
class HomeConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = "home"
        self.room_group_name = self.room_name
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await  self.accept()
        self.connected = True
        try:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        except:
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.create_task(self.send_response())

    async def send_response(self):
        while self.connected:
            sent_by = Message.objects.filter(notification_read=False).exclude(
                last_sent_by=self.scope["user"]).values("last_sent_by__username")

            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'notification_by': list(sent_by)
            }))
            await asyncio.sleep(30)

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):

        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.connected = False
```

If there is any issue or obsolete usage please correct me